# How to disable/hide Apache NetBeans 10 splash screen during the load?

Tags: user-interface, netbeans

It takes center of laptop screen; cannot be moved/hidden; appears on all workspaces. So it makes laptop almost useless while NetBeans starts. Can I launch NetBeans without splash screen? Googling doesn't help (most results relate to in-application components instead of The NetBeans Splash Screen).

Thank you

Comment: Anaksunaman, `-nosplash` doesn't work (in contrary to what stated [here] (https://markmail.org/message/iblqiipmvwvytrvo) and netbeans reports `invalid launch option`. But `--nosplash` does. Please add this as answer to the question and I will accept it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To disable the splash screen in Apache Netbeans 10, add the "--nosplash" parameter to your default options in `netbeans.conf`.

Comment: Thanks a lot! It's incredible that problem was solved so fast.

Comment: Not a problem. And thank you for the checkmark. =)